# Doctrine setAutoCommit(false) method and "there is no active transaction" message

Tags: symfony, exception, doctrine-orm, transactions

**EDIT:** The question is about why using `setAutoCommit(false)` is a solution for the "there is no active transaction" exception. **Forget this question** since this is not the correct solution (at least in my case). I will leave the question here in case somebody encounters the same problem. See my answer below for more details.

================

The following code worked fine in Symfony 2.7, but after an update to Symfony 2.8 (and to the latest `DoctrineBundle` version), a `There is no active transaction` exception is thrown:

```
private function getSynchronization() {
    $lock_repo = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MyAppBundle\Entity\DBLock');

    $this->entityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

    try {
        $sync = $lock_repo->findOneByUser($this->getUser());

        if (!$lock) {
            $lock = new DBLock();
        } else {
            if ($lock->isActive()) {
                // ... Exception: Process already running
            }
            $expected_version = $lock->getVersion();
            $this->entityManager->lock($lock, LockMode::OPTIMISTIC, $expected_version);
        }

        $sync->setActive(false);

        $this->entityManager->persist($sync);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        $this->entityManager->getConnection()->commit();

        // EXCEPTION on this line
        $this->entityManager->lock($lock, LockMode::NONE);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        $this->entityManager->getConnection()->rollback();
        throw new ProcessException($e->getMessage());
    }

    ...
}
```

After some searching I found a solution in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245357/there-is-no-active-transaction-in-catch-rollback). After adding the following line everything works fine:

```
private function getSynchronization() {
    $lock_repo = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MyAppBundle\Entity\DBLock');

    $this->entityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

    // ADDED LINE
    $this->entityManager->getConnection()->setAutoCommit(false);

    try {
        ...
```

**So, the question is not how to solve the problem, but how the solution works...**

I am quite confused by the [Doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/transactions.html#auto-commit-mode) of the `setAutoCommit()` method:

> To have a connection automatically open up a new transaction on
>   `connect()` and after `commit()` or `rollBack()`, you can disable
>   auto-commit mode with `setAutoCommit(false)`

**I do not understand this.**

Does this mean, that the transaction that was started/created with `beginTransaction()` is now automatically closed when using `commit()`? So in order to be able to use `lock(...)` after using `commit()` I have to begin a new transaction first. I can either do this manually by calling `beginTransaction()` again, or auotmatically by setting `setAutoCommit(false)` before. **Is that correct?**

Is this a change in on of the latest Doctrine versions? I did not found anything about in in the updates notes and before the update of Symfony/Doctrine the code worked just fine.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described before I encountered the problem, that calling `lock($lock, LockMode::NONE)` suddenly threw a `There is no active transaction` exception after the Update from Doctrine 2.4 to 2.5.

My solution was to add `setAutoCommit(false)`, which automatically created a new transaction after calling `commit()`. It worked and the exception did not occur again. **However, this is not the real/correct solution**, it creates other problems as side effects.

After re-reading the [Doctrine Update Notes](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/changelog/migration_2_5.html#minor-bc-break-default-lock-mode-changed-from-lockmode-none-to-null-in-method-signatures) I found out, that the correct solution is to use `lock($lock, null)` instead of `lock($lock, LockMode::NONE)`. This is BC Break between Doctrine 2.4 and 2.5.

Maybe my question and answer helps someone else who encounters the same problem.

Comment: may I ask what are the side effects of using `setAutocCommit(false)` ?